# googlemap getting Panes

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a map object lile

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);
```

and I want to get the the reference of overlayImage Pane.

How it is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, a handle to the map panes can only be obtained through the getPanes() method of the OverlayView class, and only after the draw() method has been called.
The code that returns the panes is contained in a separate module which the API loads asynchronously when needed, and for that reason it is not exposed directly as a method of the map object.
This is because the intention is to make the API as lightweight as possible for mobile devices.